# NestedScrollView in CoordinatorLayout is buggy. Fixes?

Tags: android, xml, layout, scroll

I'm trying to make a variant of the default "Scrolling View" interface on android. Basically the exact same, but with the blue page on top starting at 90% height, and a few options in the bottom white page. To do this, since I read you can't put heights in percentages, I used this code in the main and only activity:

```
//To fix the height to the right level
    Resources res = getResources();
    AppBarLayout app_bar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    float heightDp = (float)getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 100 * 87; //The percentage
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)app_bar.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = (int)heightDp;
```

### [image]

So the app project is just the default Scrolling Activity sample (CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView) + the above code.
**Problem: 
it flickers and sometimes bounces quite a lot when flinging up and down on many devices. Especially on Huawei ones, for some reason.**

---

It doesn't get better adding "snap" in app:layout_scrollFlags.
It also happens when using demo applications like cheesesquare.
I also tried converting the NestedScrollView to a ConstraintLayout, but that made it so you can't scroll up from the bottom page (from the white space) anymore.

---

Any wisdom to share?
Sorry for the long question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problems on Honor phones. Other manufacturers like sony or samsung don't share the the same behavior. But couldnt find a solution until now.

Comment: I would say they all kinda do, but not to the same degree. Not sure.